# Is there a way to apply sound effects to collisions?

Tags: swift, xcode, if-statement, sprite-kit, collision-detection

It's my first project with Swift and I'm trying to learn, but I'm stuck and can't find a solution online. Basically, it's a clone of pong, and everything is going good, until now.
My problem it's that I can't understand how to make a sound effect play, once my ball hit the paddles.
Everything else with the collisions is ok, and other sound like the goal one is playing fine. Just can't figure out how i can make a sound play when the two sprites collide.
Here's what I've written:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "main" && contact.bodyB.node?.name == "ball" || contact.bodyB.node?.name == "main" && contact.bodyA.node?.name == "ball" || contact.bodyA.node?.name == "enemy" && contact.bodyB.node?.name == "ball" || contact.bodyB.node?.name == "enemy" && contact.bodyA.node?.name == "ball" {
ball.run(blipPaddleSound)
}
}
```

It's all wrong?

I’ve already tried to break the if statement, and already tried with make one of my node run the sound effect (ball.run(‘nameofthesound’). I’ve thought maybe it could be a problem with the file, but other effect don’t play as well in that part of the code. I don’t think there is a problem with the collision, because the ball bounce on the paddle and on the wall without problem

This is the part of the code where I have put all the collision and contact mask:

```
ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 3
ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1

main.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 3
main.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
main.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 2

enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 3
enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 2
```

Comment: Remember that it is an action (.run), maybe you are removing the actions of that node.

Comment: do you refer to 'let blipPaddleSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("blipPaddle.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)'?
If so, it's still here :/

Comment: does it stop on the break point when they collide?

Comment: do you mean if i put a breakpoint in the code? no, it doesn't stop. Probably i have to write differently the collision part, i think

Comment: show the code where you set the categories or if you set them in the scene take a screenshot and show it

Comment: ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 3
ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
        
main.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 3
main.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
main.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 2
        
enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 3
enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 2

Comment: WAIT! I've changed the position of the code and it works! Probably it was in the wrong place, don't know, but now it goes! Wow, wonderful! I've alse used your tip about the 0.3 second of wait. Thank you so much

Comment: please mark my answer as correct then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are not setting the `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` to the Scene

You'll also find that a single collision can fire multiple triggers within the game cycle so you may want to put a variable controlling the sound play so that it doesn't play multiple times per collision

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    private var didCollide = false

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        let object1 = contact.bodyA.node?.name
        let object2 = contact.bodyB.node?.name

        if object1 == "ball" || object2 == "ball" {
            if object1 == "main" || object2 == "main" || object1 == "enemy"|| object2 == "enemy" {

                //check if we have just collided within the last 0.3 seconds
                if !didCollide {

                    //set the marker to true so that the sound doesn't repeatedly fire
                    didCollide = true
                    //play the sound
                    ball.run(blipPaddleSound)

                    //wait 0.3 seconds (give the ball a chance to move away from the object) 
                    self.run(.wait(forDuration: 0.3) {
                        self.didCollide = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I've settled the scene as 'SKPhysicsContactDelegate'. I've tried your code but it didn't play the effect as well, but i will remember the part about the marker so the sound doesn't go on repeat. Thank you! Maybe the problem is that i set the collision mask and the contact mask in the SpriteKit Scene, and not in the code? Don't know if it will affect anything but i will try.

Comment: if you didn't have the SKPhysicsContactDelegate set it'll never reach the didbegin code

Comment: I'm sorry! I'm new to this platform as well, did it!
Sorry again and thank you very much